# Adding conditional booleans to Terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to add a variable called 'DeployNSG' as a true/false Boolean. When I reference the variable in the resource creation for the NSG using 'Count', I am then trying to associate the NSG with Azurerm_Network_security_group_association with a subnet and it's saying that I need to use count index in the association.. however If I then try and use element to reference an item, it says you can't use element if count isn't used within the subnet association.

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "ProdNSG" {
  count = "${var.DeployNSG ? 1 : 0}"
  name                = "${var.ProdNSG}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ProdNetworkRG.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowRDP"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "ProdVNet" {
  name          = "${var.ProdVNet}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ProdNetworkRG.name}"
  address_space = "${var.ProdVNetAddressSpace}"
  location      = "${var.location}"


}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "ServersSubnet" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ProdNetworkRG.name}"
  name = "${var.ServersSubnet}"
  address_prefix = "${var.ServersSubnetAddressPrefix}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.ProdVNet.name}"

}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "ServersNSGAssociation" {
  subnet_id                 = "${azurerm_subnet.ServersSubnet.id}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.ProdNSG.id}"
}
```

True/False condition works if I comment out the association, therefore I believe this is where it is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are situations where the `count` for one resource might be zero, then in any other location where you refer to that resource you must tell Terraform how to handle the case where the other object doesn't exist.

In this case, it seems like you would not need the `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` resource at all if the network security group doesn't exist, and so the easiest answer is to apply the same `count` to that other resource:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "ProdNSG" {
  count = var.DeployNSG ? 1 : 0

  # ...other arguments as you already have set...
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "ServersNSGAssociation" {
  # Create one of this resource only if there is one of the other resource.
  count = length(azurerm_network_security_group.ProdNSG)

  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.ServersSubnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.ProdNSG[count.index].id
}
```

Notice that we can now use `count.index` when referring to `azurerm_network_security_group.ProdNSG`, because `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.ServersNSGAssociation` has the same `count` value as `azurerm_network_security_group.ProdNSG`. When one NSG exists, `count.index` will be 0 and thus it will select the first (and only) NSG instance. When no NSGs exist, no NSG attachments will exist either, and so `count.index` will never be evaluated.